# Build c# proxy for existing web service for cookie handling

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, cookies, soap

I've got a third party tool (T) through which I need to consume a web service. The problem is the service requires the client to be able to handle cookies and T can't.

The service requires you to call a Login method sets a cookie which needs to be used with future calls.

So, I've made an interim web service which does the cookie handling and returns a SessionId which is a Guid to T which T can use for subsequent calls.

I'm using a persistent dictionary

```
private Dictionary<Guid, CookieContainer> _cookieJar
```

made persistent using the `ServiceBehavior` attribute like decorating the service class like so:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ServiceClass: IServiceClass
```

to store the cookie and returned sessionId when Login is called. When T makes subsequent calls with a sessionId, I forward those requests with the corresponding CookieContainer from the dictionary attached to it using:

```
request.CookieContainer = _cookieJar[new Guid(sessionId)];
```

`request` is an `HttpWebRequest`

Like there's a Login method, there's a Logout method which effectively expires the cookie and I use this call to remove the record from the dictionary.
For cases, where the Logout call is not made, I might save the time the Cookie was created as well so I can check and remove old Cookie Containers from the dictionary as and when new ones are added.

Is there a better way or a recommended approach to make such a proxy?

Comment: personally i would use webview and use its cookies. seems like a lot easier.

Comment: The cookies are usually cookies for a reason; its hard to tell (you're only outlining what the service does); but you might be introducing a security vulnerability here - for instance I hope your session id is generated by cryptographically strong generator - because if not attacker is able to perform "hostile takeover" by stealing session id. Also dictionary is a bad idea - something like System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache is better suited for this scenario.

Comment: First of all let me just say that sessions are evil and if you can don't use them. Your code is not thread safe because of the use of Dictionary. Rather then storing the value on the server why not just add a different cookie to the incoming request of your client and set the expiration to he same date as the original?